# Can i display blog titles from my blog on another external website using iframe, HTML and CSS alone

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I am trying to display my blog posts from my website https://www.myblog.com on another website using iframe. Is there a way in which i can retrieve the blog titles of the posts alone from https://www.myblog.com and display it in a box say of width 300px and height 300px in my second website using iframe or html or css only and not by using PHP, Python, Wordpress plugins, Javascript or anything of that kind or by not using any third party sites like rssinclude.com?

Comment: How about `<iframe src="your blog" height="the exact height of your blog's h1 element">`

Comment: Say there are 3 blog posts: each blog post has a heading,content ,author,time etc. I want to display the blog headings, all three of them, with the latest one on top and it should automatically update when a new article is posted in my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that if you are limited to iframes, html, and css, just create another HTML file with the titles of blog posts in it.

Example:

```
<a href="blogpost2" target="_blank">BLOG POST (2)</a><br/>
<a href="blogpost1" target="_blank">BLOG POST (1)</a>
```

or an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="blogpost2" target="_blank">BLOG POST (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="blogpost1" target="_blank">BLOG POST (1)</a></li>
</ul>
```

using HTML and CSS with an iframe alone to fetch blog post titles is not technically possible but if you had access to PHP on the website you are trying to put it on, it would be another story.